# Feed data between systems using .net dll object

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vbscript

I’m trying to feed data from system A to system B.

System A is a C# program that collects data from an external device. The data should be feed to system B for presentation. System A also contains forms for user input and is therefore build as a Windows Forms App (Visual Studio 2017)

System B is capable of running a VBScript to collect the data.

So far, I’ve feed data to system B through a text file. However, this approach is not optimal for reasons that are not relevant to my question. So, I’ve build a .NET DLL because this can be easily instanciated in a VBScript.

My question is – how do I make system A and B share the same .NET DLL object?

I can reference the DLL in system A and feed data to the object. But in order to make the same data accessible in system B, I need to create an object in system B that will point to the same object as in system A.

How can this be done?

Comment: VBScript `CreateObject` has an optional server parameter. Note there are security issues. Read Help.

Comment: I guess you are talking about a memory mapped file? Why not use a WCF, or named pipes, or signalr, or some sort of reliable messaging, or even a database?

Comment: @ACatInLove - I don't see how this extra paramter can help. I can add it to the CreateObject in the VBScript - but in C# I'm simply creating a new instance of the object. How do you suggest that the extra parameter can help? Am I missing something in your reply?

Comment: @Saruman - I'm using the DLL approach because VBScript can easily create objects of that type. I've looked at pipes in VBScript, but when you have a VBScript as client and you want to feed data back to the client things get tricky. If I only neede to feed data from the client to the server it would be a fine approach. Are there any reasons for NOT using a .NET object since you are suggesting other ways of integration?

Comment: So the client (system B) needs to be or run vbscript?

Comment: Yes. System B is a standard system that I can not modify. The only option to fetch data in system B is through a VBScript.

Comment: Does the VbScript run continuously, or does it get called periodically ?

Comment: I can make it do both.

Comment: You export your .NET object as a COM class to call from VBScript. You cannot access that com class from C# (as .NET languages can't use COM components created in .NET languages) but you can access it internally.

Comment: VBScript can't use shared files as it requires API calls that VBScript can't do.

Comment: Look i wouldn't usually offer this as a solution to much, however i would just use signalr, its light weight its "reasonably" reliable, its simple to set up and can pipe what ever data you want. it has a small learning curve, there are lots of resources for it, you can even use it directly from a webpage if need be, or anything really... failing that, if the data is mission critical, just put in a db. and poll it. or use a wcf and poll that.

Comment: Using signalR in C# is fine, but using it in VBScript is an uphill approach.If that's the only way to make a C# program feed data to a VBScript I'll have to go that way. But is it impossible to do it through use of .net / com objects? As said - they are easily handled in VBScript so that would be my preferred approach if it can work.

Comment: Sorry i am limited by your vbscript requirements and thought this was being called form a webpage, if so, the it was your best and easiest bet. hopefully someone with more intuition in that area can help you